# Samsung Internet Browser zooms out when dragging an overflow element

Tags: android, css, samsung-mobile

I'm enabling drag to resize tab function on touch screen devices, on chrome browser is working fine. When touching an element (resize bar), it will show an overlay, which has width of the window width, then drag left or right to resize the tabs behind them. But on Samsung Internet Browser, when the overlay show up, it will overflow and zoom out and show a big chunk of white section. Any one encountered this or know how this can be solved ?

css of horizontal resize bar and overlay

```css
.resize_bar {
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    touch-action: none;
    cursor: n-resize;
    position: absolute;
}

.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

When I turned off the zoom settings in Samsung browser it is working fine, but it is preferable to not turn it off as viewing a desktop web page on mobile devices sometimes require zoom in/out to have a better view. My html code side, body have `style="overflow:hidden"`.

Comment: Plese read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: may i know how can i improve my questions ? i gave https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a read, but not too sure of what to provide more @amin

Comment: it will be better if you put the related code here